# Match two cells to place a value in Excel

Tags: excel

If I have a function

right / left

```
A     B - 1
B     C - 2
D     4 - 3
E     I - 4
I     2 - 5
4     D - 6
2     E - 7
```

How can I place the value of - x to the right side? e.g. E has 7 on the left. So moving 7 to right side

```
A     B - 1
B-1     C - 2
D-6     4 - 3
E-7     I - 4
I-4     2 - 5
4     D - 6
2     E - 7
```

I've tried using Match function and Index but I could not get what I wanted. Thank you very much.

Comment: How is this data structured in excel. Are values `A`, `B`, `D` etc.. in column `A` and values `B - 1`, `C - 2`, `4 - 3`, etc in column `B`?

Comment: So the left side value is in the coloumn A and the right side value (B - 1) is in two different columns. So it just look like 'A (empty column) B 1' in my dataset

Comment: Gotcha. In that case, this is just a `vlookup()` function. In B1 put: `=vlookup(A1, C:D, 2, false)` and it will look up the value of `A1` in column `C` and return the corrseponding value in column `D`. Sorry for the 17 hour wait!